# Mac OS user processes

Tags: security, user-account

I have a Mac OS computer with several user accounts.

When a user closes his session, is it possible for him to keep some process running in background ?

Or closing session kills every user's processes ?

Thanks

Comment: Do the experiment and use Activity Monitor. Some background processes survive after logout.

Comment: What kind of processes would you need to keep running? Would using Fast User Switching be an option?

Comment: I just want to be sure a user cannot run a malware if i give him a temp access to a mac computer